# how to Join two tables get the recored show on not exists id null rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|              student Details              |
+-------------------------------------------+
|DetailsID(Idendtity)| StudentID| subjectID |
|      1             |  101     |    1001   |
|      2             |  101     |    1002   |   
+-------------------------------------------+

+-------------------------------------------+
|              Assign student               |
+-------------------------------------------+
|   AssingID         | StudentID| subjectID |
|      1             |  101     |    1001   |
|      1             |  101     |    1002   |   
+-------------------------------------------+
```

I wanted Expected Result mentioned below.
Here's the SQL query :

```
SELECT Distinct * FROM
   tbl_Studentdetails s LEFT OUTER JOIN  
   tbl_Assignstudent a ON s.studentID = a.studentID
   WHERE AssignId=1
```

Actual Result :

```
+----------------------------------------+
| StudentID | subjectID | Exam 1 | Exam2 | 
|   101     |    1001   |  10:00 | 10:00 |
|   101     |    1002   |  01:00 | 02:00 |
+----------------------------------------+
```

Expected Result:

```
+----------------------------------------+
| StudentID | subjectID | Exam 1 | Exam2 | 
|   101     |    1001   |  10:00 | 10:00 |
|   101     |    1002   |  01:00 | 02:00 |
|   101     |    1003   |  NULL  | NULL  |
+----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: There is no `subjectID 1003`. Same thing for `Exam1, Exam2` columns. From where they comes?

Comment: sorry, i missed first table last row in student table subjectID 1003

Comment: @asanraj . . . No it doesn't.  You should edit the question to show the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

The AssignId condition in the `WHERE` clause makes the `LEFT JOIN` return regular `INNER JOIN` result. Move the condition to the `ON` clause to get true `LEFT JOIN` result:

```
SELECT Distinct * FROM
   tbl_Studentdetails s LEFT OUTER JOIN  
   tbl_Assignstudent a ON s.studentID = a.studentID
   AND AssignId=1
```